# Unknown naming convention - Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have synthesized some verilog and this is what I am getting out. Where can I get more info on what this naming convention is called and when you would want to use it. I have never seen it before.

```
wire \genblk1.U_inverter_n_572 , \genblk1.U_inverter_n_575 ,
       \genblk1.U_inverter_n_578 , \genblk1.U_inverter_n_581 ,
       \genblk1.U_inverter_n_584 , \genblk1.U_inverter_n_587 ,
       \genblk1.U_inverter_n_590 , \genblk1.U_inverter_n_591 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called an **escaped identifier** (See section 5.6.1 in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM). In this case, it looks like it came from flattening out a unnamed `generate` block of code.

Answer (score 0):

In general identifiers in verilog consist of numbers, letters, underscores and $.

However in some cases, usually created by some type of generators or flatteners automatically, escaped names are generated. Theses names allow any character between `\` and a space to be a part of them. In your case the unusual character `.` becomes a simple part of the name. No hierarchy, nor xmr is expressed there. It is a simple local variable name.

The first part of it 'genblk' looks like a part of the unnamed generate block naming convention.

For more info please look in the section 5.6.1 of an lrm, as suggested in other replies.